# React Table Takes time to load from api

Tags: reactjs, api, material-ui

I am new to react and I am currently working on a material-ui dashboard where they had dummy data inside a json file which they used to populate a Table. I changed the dummy data and started calling the data from a mock api using axios. Everything works fine except the table takes about 5 seconds  to load the data after each page load. Is there a way we can speed this up? I have experience working in php with bootstrap dashboards but I never encountered such an issue there. Any advice is appreciated. Thankyou.

Comment: Have you used your browser's dev tools' profiler to figure out what's taking up that time?

Comment: No, I will have look. Forgot to mention the api gives the data pretty quick because the values are being consoled logged as soon as the page loads.

Comment: That's not what I'd call "solving itself". ;) You can self-answer this with "adding keys to the list helped" with a suitable code snippet.

Comment: I will do that but  there is a still a bit of lag like 2 secs for fetching and populating data. Is there a way to solve that in the frontend or should I optimize the API?

Comment: Look at the profiler to figure out where that time is being spent.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the key I gave was not a unique value. I changed the key value to index of the data and the time was improved significantly.